# A question about order statistics

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, order-statistics

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n\overset{iid}{\sim}F_X$ be random variables. Let $b\in(0,\infty)$, and consider the transformation:

$$
Y_i=bF_X(X_i)\\
i=1,\dots,n
$$

How do I calculate the order statistic $Y_{(n)}?$

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I cannot find the distribution of maximum order statistic ${{Y}_{(n)}}$

Comment: What progress have you made on this [tag:self-study] question? For instance, what is the distribution of the $Y_i?$

Comment: It would probably be easier if you started with $b=1$ and then scaled at the end.  You may need to assume $F_X$ is continuous to make progress